# How can a specific user opt out from fire base analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase analytics for my android application. I want to remove myself and my teams from the firebase analytics for better analysis of user data. How can I do it ?

Mixpanel has a simple optout page in web for similar use case . you can look at that page [here](https://mixpanel.com/optout/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from the Firebase Support team . It is not possible to remove the analytics data generated by your teammates during development or during testing phase. They advise to create separate projects for testing and production

> Hi Jani,
>
> I hope you're doing well and thank you for reaching out to us. If you
>   meant like removing the analytics data generated by your teammates
>   during development or testing phase, then it is not possible. In this
>   case, we usually advise our developers to create separate projects,
>   one for test or development phase and for production.
>
> To disable the analytics collection in your app, please check out this
>   documentation.
>
> If you have any other questions or clarifications, just let me know.
>   Thank you.
>
> Regards,

Answer (score 0):

[`setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(boolean)) will let you conditionally turn Analytics data collection on/off.

Disabling Analytics collection on a per-app basis is addressed in the Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#temporarily_disable_collection).